# images and css not displaying in Symfony on Xampp Server

Tags: symfony, xampp

I have downloaded the Symfony project and added the database. 
But when I am going to **web** folder then on the home page. Images and CSS not displaying.

It is showing like below,

http://localhost/uploads/logos/image.jpg

** but my project is on a folder name like /folder/ **

All the images and css have broken links.

Answer (score 0):

How did you run the web server? Try this,

`Symfony v2.* = php app/console s:r`

`Symfony v3.* = php bin/console s:r`

If you want to Xampp Server, you should change the root directory;

`project_directory/web`

Comment: I am currently using it on xammp. Did you use 80 port? Have you uploads and logos directories really?

Answer (score 0):

In this matter virtual host is the best solution.

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName project.local
      ServerAlias www.project.local

      DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\web"
      <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\web">
          Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Allow from All
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```